# How to open the datapump file (External Table Oracle)?

Tags: oracle

I am going to unload the data from my table in Oracle DB to a file using oracle datapump. I am aware that I can import the file in to a different DB using datapump but would like to know if there is any other way to import or open the file?

i.e After the file is generated, I am going to send the file to my client who has no idea about Oracle DB etc. So is there any software or UI using which my client can open the file rather than using Oracle datapump to import  (if no other go I will educate the client)? The reason I am going for external table etc because I have 50 million records that client wants to view.

Comment: Yes looks like they will analyse the data. Excel can accommodate only  1048576 rows. So I am going for external table.

Comment: You want them to create an external table with [the data pump access driver](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_dp_driver.htm), rather than importing (with `impdp`); and you're unloading with that access driver? As the docs say: "The data in the file is written in a binary format that can only be read by the ORACLE_DATAPUMP access driver". I'm not aware of anything else that would attempt to open such a file. If they do not already have/know Oracle then it might not be the more appropriate format though.

Comment: So if I use impdp, can I generate the file in a .csv or text format and give it to client?

Comment: No, `impdp` is to import data into a database; `expdp` does the equivalent export, but also in binary format. I think you're starting from the wrong end - what does the client want to receive? Presumably not an Oracle format, from what you've said. What tools do they *want* to use? Maybe they can cope with CSV (even if not for Excel), or XML, or even plain text though that would be hard to parse.

Comment: The client just can use excel.  I think I have to educate them on Oracle so that I can use the external table

Comment: That's a significant investment in time and (maybe) licences to handle a single file. Maybe you can do their analysis on your copy of the data, or give them remote access to your copy, or use multiple CSV files, or something. Good luck.